# Open source video encoders for an embedded system

Tags: c++, c, linux, voip, embedded-linux

I recently designed an [H.323](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.323)/[SIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol) compliant video server (in code at least) fully equipped with a sockets based API which a .NET SDK would use, and a web server, you know ... all of that stuff. Anyway, I chose to use OPAL for my call stack and based my architecture loosely upon the design of EKIGA. I even hijacked the serial ports for digital [I/O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input/output) with two outputs and three inputs.

Everything works great from my Linux P.C.. I built my own [Linux distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) specifically for the new boards with the [Intel Atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Atom) processors with 2 GB of [RAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory). The problem? The Atom processors can't handle the load of the encoders. The maximum frame rate I ever pull is about 7 FPS on [NTSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTSC). It does this regardless of bitrate. I know I don't have any memory leaks, however the [CPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit) load rises to about 130% between two cores so really about 66% total. I really don't want to have to change stacks, but I don't know what I need to do. Are there some lighter weight encoders I can convert into PWLIB plugins?

The problem happens regardless of video encoder, [H.261](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.261), theora, [H.263+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.263#H.263v2_.28H.263.2B.29), etc... What should be my next plan of attack?

Update:

OK, so I think my next move is going to be to find a very low profile [PCIe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express) [GPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit) that is [OpenGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL) compatible; it needs to lay parallel to the motherboard. How can I do that? Also, am I barking up the wrong tree? I am just a programmer, so please pardon my ignorance.

Additional question:

Assuming that I get another board with a GPU. How do I make sure that the encoding is done on the GPU and not on the CPU? Is this managed by the OS and the driver? Do I need to write special code to do so? Also, it seems to me that the main function of the GPU is in rendering and output, does it also manage actual transforms and encoding? A good book recommendation would be nice.

**More information**:

I suspect now that the GPU is not the problem. I think it may have something to do with the temporal spatial tradeoff. I mounted the flash on my overclocked i7 950 and had the same exact problem. I discovered that the framerate drops on motion, but that if there is no motion then I can keep a high framerate. I also talked to one of the architects at OPAL VoIP and they also doubt that the GPU is the problem. What else could the problem be?

Comment: Have you thought of possibly x264?

Comment: @Mike I am using x264 as a ptlib plugin. The problem is that it uses more resources than the h261 and theora encoders. Plus to maintain SIP/H323 compliance I have to support at least h261.

Comment: Do you mean resources as in CPU usage and/or memory usage? IIRC, there's a number things you can do to reduce either if they're problematic for you. If maintaining low latency, real-time encoding is an issue, you can actually configure x264 to achieve both and be very light on CPU. One patch is available that actually adjusts parameters as necessary to attain a target frame rate, while maintaining good video quality. The x264 developers are very willing to work with people who wish to extend it in areas like this.

Comment: @Mike, there are a number of things I can do if, I write the PWLIB plugin for OPAL. Otherwise, I am at the mercy of the developer who created the one I am using and his/her assumptions. I will probably end up writing my own plugins for all of the codecs, but for now, I just want this video server to get to beta. By resources, I mean cpu usage % it hits about 130 on two cores, so about 66% for one call. I am using x264 extensively for gstreamer (x264enc) and I love it. It still uses more resources than anything else, even with optimizations.

Comment: Well if you want some more help working that out, you can get in contact with the developers of x264 directly. You can usually find them at http://forum.doom9.org/forumdisplay.php?f=77, http://doom10.org/index.php?board=5.0. But, you might have better luck contacting them on their IRC channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the time for microptimisation: Time to look carefully at your inner loops.

You need to figure out which inner loops matter, and then look carefully at how you can get the most throughput. You can also do a sanity check: Can the machine really do what you want to do? Eg. if you need to do n multiple/accumulate operations and you have n/3 cycles, there is a basic problem and you need to do something else.

Comment: The problem is, I didn't write the encoders and I don't have access to them. The h263 and h264 encoders are ffmpeg, but the rest come with PTLIB. I have no idea how to go about analyzing these. I also, don't have the knowledge base to do so. I know the problem lies with the encoders. Is there a body of encoders specifically for embedded systems? There is only one loop, and it isn't nested, being called to grab the video frames.

Comment: If the ffmpeg encoders are running that slow, you probably have the options horribly wrong. Are you perhaps converting back and forth from YUV to RGB and back? Enabling high-qualify/high-compression options?

Comment: I haven't even made it to the testing of the ffmpeg encoders because I can't get h261 or theora to work right. Also, I don't know if you are familiar with OPAL or not, but it is built on top of PTLIB, so all of the encoders are PTLIB plugins. I don't mind writing a new plugin, ( a little c and assembly would be a nice break-challenge ) I just want to make sure that that is the problem before I start. In OPAL I can only set things like, max fps, max tx, max rx, temporal spatial tradeoff for each encoder. If I want to change much more, I need to rewrite the plugin for the encoder.

Comment: Actually you are right. I should have scrapped all of Ekiga's code because they have too many nested loops and a ton of synchronization locks. This is the issue.

Answer (score 2):

An Atom alone is probably not up to the task.  Some Atom boards are equipped with a GPU that may be used to offload the encoding.  Otherwise, look at a board with a DSP or dedicated video codec hardware that can do the encoding.

Comment: @karunski, if I mount a pci-e gpu for hardware acceleration on the board would it help if this was the problem?

Comment: @karunski, ok so these intel Johnstown boards come with GMA 950. I am assuming that is not sufficient?

Comment: I am about to attempt with a Integrated VIA Unichrome Pro AGP graphics with MPEG-2 decoding acceleration

Comment: The boards I had in mind were equipped with a NVidia ION chipset.  You may end up writing a codec in OpenCL to actually do the encoding on the GPU. I don't know if the Intel or VIA chips are capable of this.

Comment: @karunski So, if I get this guy, http://www.logicsupply.com/products/ipx7a_ion330 is it going to be a pain in the ass to run on Linux since nvidia is proprietary?

Comment: @karunski Also, what about one of these guys http://www.logicsupply.com/products/bcm970015 ? Would something like this help? It seems it is only for decoding. Would it help on the encoding side?